# Constantly separated validation & training losses

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, autoencoder

I've worked with Autoencoders for some weeks now, but I've seem to hit a rock wall when it comes to my understanding of losses overall. The issue I'm facing is that when trying to implement Batchnormalization & Dropout layers to my model, I get losses which aren't converging and awful reconstructions. A typical loss plot is something like this: [image]
and the losses I use is an L1 regularization with MSE loss and looks something like this

```
def L1_loss_fcn(model_children, true_data, reconstructed_data, reg_param=0.1, validate):
    mse = nn.MSELoss()
    mse_loss = mse(reconstructed_data, true_data)

    l1_loss = 0
    values = true_data
    if validate == False:
        for i in range(len(model_children)):
            values = F.relu((model_children[i](values)))
            l1_loss += torch.sum(torch.abs(values))

        loss = mse_loss + reg_param * l1_loss
        return loss, mse_loss, l1_loss
    else: 
        return mse_loss
```

with my training loop written as:

```
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
    train_run_loss = 0
    val_run_loss = 0
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1} of {epochs}")
        
        # TRAINING
        model.train()
           for data in tqdm(train_dl):
               x, _ = data
               reconstructions = model(x)
               optimizer.zero_grad()
               train_loss, mse_loss, l1_loss =L1_loss_fcn(model_children=model_children, true_data=x,reg_param=regular_param,                                             reconstructed_data=reconstructions, validate=False)
               train_loss.backward()
               optimizer.step()
               train_run_loss += train_loss.item()
         # VALIDATING 
         model.eval()
           with torch.no_grad():
               for data in tqdm(test_dl):
                   x, _ = data
                   reconstructions = model(x)
                   val_loss = L1_loss_fcn(model_children=model_children, true_data=x, reg_param=regular_param, reconstructed_data = reconstructions, validate = True)
                    val_run_loss += val_loss.item()
       
    epoch_loss_train = train_run_loss / len(train_dl)
    epoch_loss_val = val_run_loss / len(test_dl)
```

where I've tried different hyper-parameter values without luck. My model looks something like this,

```
encoder = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(), nn.Dropout(p=0.5), nn.LeakyReLU(), nn.BatchNorm1d(),
                        nn.Linear(), nn.Dropout(p=0.4), nn.LeakyReLU(), nn.BatchNorm1d(),
                        nn.Linear(), nn.Dropout(p=0.3), nn.LeakyReLU(), nn.BatchNorm1d(),
                        nn.Linear(), nn.Dropout(p=0.2), nn.LeakyReLU(), nn.BatchNorm1d(),
)
decoder = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(), nn.Dropout(p=0.2), nn.LeakyReLU(),
                        nn.Linear(), nn.Dropout(p=0.3), nn.LeakyReLU(), 
                        nn.Linear(), nn.Dropout(p=0.4), nn.LeakyReLU(), 
                        nn.Linear(), nn.Dropout(p=0.5), nn.ReLU(), 
)
```

What I expect to find is a converging train & validation loss, and thereby a lot better reconstructions overall, but I think that I'm missing something quite grave I'm afraid. Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not comparing apples to apples, your code reads

```
    l1_loss = 0
    values = true_data
    if validate == False:
        for i in range(len(model_children)):
            values = F.relu((model_children[i](values)))
            l1_loss += torch.sum(torch.abs(values))

        loss = mse_loss + reg_param * l1_loss
        return loss, mse_loss, l1_loss
    else: 
        return mse_loss
```

So your validation loss is just MSE, but training is MSE + regularization, so obviously your train loss will be higher. You should log *just* train MSE without regulariser if you want to compare them.

Also, do not start with regularisation, always start witha model with no regularisation at all and get training to converge. Remove all extra losses, remove your dropouts. These things only harm your ability to learn (but might improve generalisation). Once this is achieved - reintroduce them one at a time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll definitely do this. If I have a model with a nice converging loss, but I still find that the reconstruction is poor, do you have any tips on how to improve the reconstruction? Most of my tests, when introducing e.g. batchnorm layers has just failed miserably.